# Creating Draftail entity with additional data

Tags: django, wagtail, draftail

I've been using Wagtail to create a website with additional text annotations. The user flow is that there is some highlighted text in a paragraph, which when clicked shows an annotation off to one side. The expected HTML result is:

```
A sentence with <span class='link'>A link<span class='hidden-text'>Hidden text</span></span>
```

I would like to achieve this with a single item on the draftail menu, with a UI similar to the URL creator- the user selects the text, and adds the annotation text.
I have followed the instructions on https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_draftail.html to create a new inline style which produces the `link`, however I can't then add the `hidden-text`:

```
# 1. Use the register_rich_text_features hook.
@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_mark_feature(features):
    """
    Registering the `mark` feature, which uses the `MARK` Draft.js inline style type,
    and is stored as HTML with a `<mark>` tag.
    """
    feature_name = 'mark'
    type_ = 'SAMPLE'
    tag = 'sample'

    # 2. Configure how Draftail handles the feature in its toolbar.
    control = {
        'type': type_,
        'label': '?',
        'description': 'Hint link',
    }

    # 3. Call register_editor_plugin to register the configuration for Draftail.
    features.register_editor_plugin(
        'draftail', feature_name, draftail_features.InlineStyleFeature(control)
    )

    # 4.configure the content transform from the DB to the editor and back.
    db_conversion = {
        'from_database_format': {tag: InlineStyleElementHandler(type_)},
        'to_database_format': {'style_map': {type_: tag}},
    }

    # 5. Call register_converter_rule to register the content transformation conversion.
    features.register_converter_rule('contentstate', feature_name, db_conversion)

    # 6. (optional) Add the feature to the default features list to make it available
    # on rich text fields that do not specify an explicit 'features' list
    features.default_features.append('mark')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get What you want, easiest way is to create your own **Template tags filters**, create your own markdown replacements, let's say, in the rich text you assigned the link to part of your paragraph like this "Click here this is a hidden text"  and then you put [ht] right before the "this is a hidden text" and a[th] right after that targeted hidden text,then in the template use `self.field_name|replace:"[ht]"|replace:"[th]"`

in template tag file (for example myapp/templatetags/my_richtext.py):

```
from django import template
from wagtail.images.models import Image
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


register = template.Library()


@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
def replace(value, arg, autoescape=True):
    if arg == "[ht]": result = value.replace(arg, "<span class='hidden'>")
    elif arg == "[th]": result = value.replace(arg, "</span>")
    return mark_safe(result)
```